# Error creating token via softhsm2 as non-root user "Could not initialize the library"

Tags: pkcs#11, softhsm

Whilst initializing a token via softhsm2-util as a non-root user I receive the following error:

```
$ softhsm2-util --init-token --slot 0  --label "test" --so-pin 5462 --pin 8764329

ERROR: Could not initialize the library.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Whilst initializing token as a non-root user, we invariably try to access the default `/etc/softhsm/softhsm2.conf` which points tokens to be staged under `/var/lib/softhsm/tokens` whose ownership/permission is limited to be used by root and its associated groups.

Changing ownership/permission of `/var/lib/softhsm/tokens` doesn't solve the problem as we cannot access `/etc/softhsm/softhsm2.conf` in the first place given the access limitation, so we should be doing this instead:

```
cd $HOME
mkdir -p $HOME/lib/softhsm/tokens
cd $HOME/lib/softhsm/
echo "directories.tokendir = $PWD/tokens" > softhsm2.conf
export SOFTHSM2_CONF=$HOME/lib/softhsm/softhsm2.conf

$ softhsm2-util --init-token --slot 0 --label "test" --so-pin 5462 --pin 8764329
The token has been initialized.
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add `export SOFTHSM2_CONF=$HOME/lib/softhsm/softhsm2.conf` to your .bashrc file too (or for whatever shell you use) so that subsequent shells can still run the command without root.